# Apache HttpClient post request with non string values in body

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I'm using Apache HttpClient version 4.5.13 and I'm having trouble creating my POST request body. From the tutorials I've seen online, they tell me to use `NameValuePair` when creating the request entity. However, `NameValuePair` only accepts String for the values.

How can I set Integer, Double, and Booleans as well? The API I'm calling has a mixture of them in the JSON body. For example, my body can look like this:

```json
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Test",
  "accepted": false,
  "street": "foo bar ave."
}
```

This is how the documentations recommend I create the body:

```java
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<NameValuePair> body = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    body.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", Integer.valueOf(3)));
    body.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Test"));
    body.add(new BasicNameValuePair("accepted", Boolean.valueOf(false)));
    body.add(new BasicNameValuePair("street", "foo bar ave."));
    
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://my-url.com/test-api");
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(body));
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    
    // etc...
}
```

But as you can see, I have to convert everything to String which the API I'm calling rejects because of the mismatch of data types. Is there some other way I can create the request which accepts various data types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using `StringEntity`. I converted the code in the question to the following:

```java
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("id", 3);
    jsonObject.put("name", "Test");
    jsonObject.put("accepted", false);
    jsonObject.put("street", "foo bar ave.");
    
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://my-url.com/test-api");
    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString()));
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    
    // etc...
}
```

And I was able to call the API in question without any errors. Hopefully, this helps someone!